# Trying to ssh my git server with private key, asks also for a password

Tags: ssh, git

I setup my git server with user `git` without password.
`git` home directory is `/media/nas/programming/git_repos` where I have a file `./.ssh/authorized_keys` with my public key.

I am trying to push with `git-gui` from windows unsuccessfully. It asks for a password.

Now I am trying to connect with ssh with `ssh -T git@10.0.0.2` and the interactive dialog is:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd>ssh -T git@10.0.0.2
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\chameleon/.ssh/id_rsa':
git@10.0.0.2's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@10.0.0.2's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Ok, what is this password? `git` user does not have a password. I set correctly the passphrase (or else asks again).

Comment: Have you looked at the SSH server's logs for clues? What UID owns the `git` account's home directory, as well as the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file? What permissions do those have?

Answer (score 0):

I forget, on server side, to add new user `git` on allowed users of ssh daemon.
This is possible with adding `git` user on `AllowUsers` of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, on server.

After that, problem fixed for both ssh and git clients.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).